# How to make JQuery .hover() work when mouse leaves viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, viewport, jquery-hover

The below code will put a div at the very top of the view port.

The expected behavior is:

When the user mouses over the div, then moves the mouse up until the cursor is out of the viewport, a message of "hover out" should be logged in the console. The issue is that nothing gets logged to the console.

How can I make JQuery .hover() log something to the console when the mouse leaves viewport?

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <div class="foo" style="background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    Test
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(".foo").hover(function(){
        console.log("hover in");
    }, function(){
        console.log("hover out");
    });

   </script>
```

Comment: Problem is with this code that there's nothing else in your body, so the foo is stretched to the whole body, and will never leave it. Put more content in the body and it should work.

Comment: Your exact code works fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/banksbiz/GXHhf/

Comment: I concur with Banx.  Firebug's console is being written to perfectly.

Comment: Jerone, in the source code example given in the question, the width and height of the div are specified, so the div is not stretching to the whole body as you suggested.

Comment: Banx, I don't think my code is working as you said. Please try making an html document containing the code and you should be able to replicate the issue. The issue occurs when the div is flush with the top of the viewport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change the JQuery version from 1.5.1 to 1.4.4. Not a good solution, but it works.

Comment: Very interesting! Do you have a link to where you came across this? Or was it just trial-and-error?

Comment: It was just trial and error. The working dropdown menu can be seen at the top of this page: http://goo.gl/oSeYz

Comment: O..k, you probably should put the domain name in there somewhere instead of the shortened link so that no one gets into trouble following it at, say, their workplace! Or at least qualify it as slightly NSFW :)

Answer (score 8):

Using `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead of `hover` seems to fix it.

```
$(".foo").mouseover(function(){
    console.log("hover in");
});

$(".foo").mouseout(function(){
    console.log("hover out");
});
```

**[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/GXHhf/1/).**

Note that even this won't work if there is no chrome around the browser window. For example, when I maximize FF4 or put it into full screen mode, the edge of the browser window is flush with the edge of my screen so there is nowhere for the cursor to go to the left of the div in that case so the mouseout event will never fire.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but as my question says, I need it to work with .hover(). My example is a simple test case, but the "real" code is for a dropdown menu which relies on .hover()

Comment: @edt Sorry, didn't realize that when you asked for how to get  `hover()` to work, you were open to other options; you might want to state that explicitly in your question. That might be a problem because, from what I can tell, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are only fired when the mouse pointer enters/leaves an element from/for another element. And that element is `null` in this case when the div is flush with the browser viewport so the events are never fired. Note that `hover` simply binds both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Is it adding `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers in addition to `hover` an option? To handle the special case of when you mouseout out of the browser?

Comment: See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/GXHhf/2/) - I won't claim that this is the final solution; it seem that there might be a number of special cases and since you mentioned this just a toy example, this might not even be feasible.

Comment: I tried entering the mouseout handler in addition to hover, but the result was that it's not possible to mouse over the dropdown links (they vanish when you mouse out of their parent). I tried adding the mouseout handler to body, ul, li, etc with no luck. I found that switching from JQuery 1.5.1 to 1.4.4 fixes the issue and submitted a bug report to JQuery